# Router using different ip address when modem is in bridged mode

Tags: networking, router, voip

I have a zyxel modem/router that is blocking my voip, and so I want to put it into bridge mode. When in bridge mode, I use my own router, and my voip works fine.

We have 5 static ip addresses at our office, and the zyxel has it's own sixth address. When I am in bridge mode, I am reported as using the zyxel specific ip and can't use the 5 statics that we have.

So the zyxel has something like 100.10.10.10 when in bridge mode, but when in router mode, it has that same address as well as 5 100.100.100.100 address available to my servers. I use static ip addressing in my router (a linksys WRT54G2) and simply have copied the info from the zyxel before putting it into bridge mode.

How do I go about setting up the linksys so that those 5 static ip's (set in static by the servers behind the linksys) are seen when on the web as those ip's? (hosting my site and email, etc)

Answer (score 0):

NAT cannot be enabled on the Linksys router in bridge mode.

To achieve what you are asking you will need to [cascade another router](http://kb.linksys.com/Linksys/ukp.aspx?pid=8&vw=1&articleid=3733).

If your zyxel is in bridge mode, all you need to do is cascade the Linksys, and [set it in NAT](http://ciscoskills.net/2011/01/21/configuring-nat-one-to-one-mapping/) mode, your servers should be able to talk out to the net.

Comment: The zyxel is the one in bridge mode...not the linksys.

Comment: In that case all you need to do is enable NAT on the Linksys, and everything should work for you.

Comment: Ya, I did that and it technically does work as the computers and servers do get onto the internet. But the 5 static ip's are not accessible outside the network (ie. on the internet). The current  zyxel takes the nat-ted addresses and makes them publicly accessible as my 5 static ip's so I can host on those ip's. I want the linksys to do the same: Take those 5 ip's and make them publicly accessible via the internet. Someone on the internet should be able to type in one of those 5 ip's that are behind the linksys and access whatever sites and services I make available...right through the linksys

Comment: You will need a static route on the zyxel pointing those IP's to the Linksys and then a NAT on the Linksys like I said.